# Creating a custom Leaflet control with React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, nodes

Using `leaflet 1.7.1`, `react 17.0.2`, `react-leaflet 3.1.0`.

I am trying to create a custom Leaflet control in a React project starting from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62947152/react-leaflet-v3-custom-control) and using `createControlComponent()` function to do so.

So in my `MyControl.js` file I have:

```
import { createControlComponent } from '@react-leaflet/core'
import ownStyles from '../style/MyControl.module.css'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import L from 'leaflet'

L.MyControl = L.Control.extend({
  onAdd: function (map) {
    return (
      <Container className={ownStyles.mainContainer}>
        My container!
      </Container>
    )
  },

  onRemove: function (map) {}
})

export const MyControl = createControlComponent(
  (props) => new L.MyControl(props)
)
```

and I use it in `App.js` with:

```
import { MyControl } from './components/MyControl'
import { MapContainer } from 'react-leaflet'

<MapContainer>
  <MyControl />
</MapContainer>
```

This configuration returns me the error `Uncaught TypeError: el.className is undefined`.

I tried to add/remove the `className` attribute both to/from the tags `<MyControl />` and `<Container />` without success.

One undesired solution found was **not** using React components within the Leaflet control, i.e.:

```
(...)
onAdd: function (map) {
    const retDiv = L.DomUtil.create('div')
    retDiv.innerHTML = 'A DIV THAT WORKS!'
    return retDiv
  },
(...)
```

So it seems that there is an incompatibility in the configuration of 'React component inside custom Leaflet control'.

Am I missing something? Any workaround?

Or do we MUST use `L.DomUtil` objects to build custom Leaflet controls?